# Can we have multiple case then statements in sql

Tags: sql, case, teradata

I am trying for something which requires case within case I just wanted to make sure if we can  use multiple case then?I am running this on sql teradata
The code I am trying to use is as below

```
AND(
    case when CHARACTER_LENGTH(drug.n)=0 then 0 

     when CHARACTER_LENGTH(drug.n)=1 then
     (case when substring(drug.n from  1,1) in            (''0'',''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''5'',''6'',''7'',''8'',''9'') then 1 else 0 end)


     when CHARACTER_LENGTH(drug.n)=2 then 
     (case when substring(drug.n from  1,1) in (''0'',''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''5'',''6'',''7'',''8'',''9'') then 1 else 0 end *
     case when substring(drug.n from  2,1) in (''0'',''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''5'',''6'',''7'',''8'',''9'') then 1 else 0 end ) 


     when CHARACTER_LENGTH(drug.n)=3 then 
     (case when substring(drug.n from  1,1) in (''0'',''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''5'',''6'',''7'',''8'',''9'') then 1 else 0 end *
     case when substring(drug.n from  2,1) in (''0'',''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''5'',''6'',''7'',''8'',''9'') then 1 else 0 end *
     case when substring(drug.n from  3,1) in (''0'',''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'',''5'',''6'',''7'',''8'',''9'') then 1 else 0 end )=1
```

If somebody has better idea you can let me know. I cannot use isnumeric function.

Comment: Ummm...you mean `('0','1','2',...etc)` rather than `(''0'',''1'',...etc)`, right?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to do it like this / what you are trying to achieve etc?

Comment: Plus, wouldn't it be easier to just check via a regex (`case when substring(drug.n from 1,1)~'[0-9]'`...etc)?

Comment: There is no regexpr defined in teradata 12 and thats my rdbms I am working on. I cannot define any UDF's as I dont have the access rights. I have tried it my self but its taking really long to finish so just wanted to make sure if my syntax is correct or not.What I am trying to do here is I am checking if the cell in drug.n column has 0 elements and if yes return 1 if it has 1 element it checks if that is a number and if it returns 1 else 0 similarly for the others. I knwo this logic dosent look impresive but i have very few options in teradata to replace the regexpr kind of functions

Comment: What I am trying to find is can I have a case block within a then statement? Is that correct because I checked it online and I don't see any such example..

Comment: Do you need to worry about special characters like underscores? If it's only alphanumeric, there's a much neater solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use nested `CASE` statements. No problems with that in Teradata

Answer (score 0):

Okay -
To determine whether an arbitrary length string contains only numeric characters (or does not), you can use a recurive CTE.

Please note that I don't know whether or not your RDBMS actually supports recursive CTEs, but this is a potential solution.  Also, I'm not sure of the performance implications - however, it does remove the multiple `CASE` effect (And why isn't that an actual numeric field, anyways?).

So... For a table that looks like this:

```
id   ch
================
1   1234567890
2   asdg
```

This statement returns all rows that contain *only* numeric characters (of any length):

```
WITH splitstring (id, chard, start, orig) as (
                  SELECT id, SUBSTRING(ch, 1, 1), 1, ch
                  FROM chartable
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT id, SUBSTRING(orig, start + 1, 1), start + 1, orig
                  FROM splitstring
                  WHERE LENGTH(orig) > start)
SELECT * 
FROM chartest as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                  FROM splitstring as b
                  WHERE a.id = b.id
                  AND chard NOT BETWEEN '0' AND '9')
```

Without some of the larger context it's somewhat difficult to know exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  However, this should be adaptable for your needs.

(As a side note, DB2 for the iSeries doesn't seem to support regex either...)